# Pyspark Enforce Nullability on Read of Json File

Tags: python, pyspark, nullable

I'm trying to read a json file and enforce a schema on read using SQLContext but the nullability part seems to get ignored. 
I have a schema something like this:

```
StructType(List(StructField(some_field,StringType,false), StructField(some_other_field,StringType,false))
```

Now then, I want to read a json file and enforce that schema onto it as such:

```
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlc.read.load("path/to/file", format="json", schema=schema)
```

The field names and data type seem to work just fine, but no matter what I put in for nullability, all the columns have nullable = true as such:

```
root
 |--some_field: string (nullable = true)
 |--some_other_field: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I enforce nullability on my columns on read?

FYI. I'm using Python 2.7, pyspark 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

According to the research I've found, this is a bug in Spark that did not get resolved until Spark 2.0.0. I would love if someone who is using Spark 2.0.0 or higher could confirm this bug is fixed, but until then, here is the Apache Jira ticket discussing the issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11319